# Do I have to create index in database for lat & lng columns when i want to create area search?

Tags: mysql, database, maps

I want to create a query to check if there's any restaurant in their area using lat lng as input. Then the lat & lng data will be stored in database. If I have a million restaurants data, do I have to create index for the lat & lng columns?

Comment: what do you mean by index, can you brief with an example ?

Comment: @MuhammadShaharyar i mean index in SQL database, because i assume that the data is so big and i need fast query for my search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can use indexing for big data

you can see structural example :
[image]

for more detail you can go for :

> [Big Data SQL Quick Start. Storage Indexes](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/big-data-sql-quick-start-storage-indexes-part10)
>
> [SQL Server Indexing Questions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/14-sql-server-indexing-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)